# How do you deal with Math Frustration?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, education

So I'm covering Algebra 1 and 2 atm and I'm wondering how you guys deal with frustration regarding math problems. Sometimes I find myself watching explanations and just can't figure out how it makes sense, so I get frustrated, leave for a couple hours. When I return I usually sit with it for 5 min and it turns out to make sense. I get this quite a lot and it interrupts my study sessions. Tips/Tricks?

Comment: appreciate the pattern, and enjoy couple of hours of inbetween, instead of getting frustrated.

Comment: For me, being English, about 300 cups of tea a day

Comment: Some people (including professionals) can't just cram hours of material at a time. For them, learning has to happen slowly with breaks, so that their minds can digest it.

Comment: Always start by studying carefully the *simplest examples*.

Comment: Crudely put, just how athletes dedicate hours and hours in the gym to master their craft, we have to as well. There are no tricks. Just another heads up, one time it took me months to understand a definition, but I didn't give up. Also, take pride in your work. People in my dept acknowledge me as the topology guy, not because there aren't others who know more topology (because there certainly are), but because I talk about it with so much excitement and always willing to help someone with a question in that field. A lot of times, me helping is just me being frustrated along with them :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Second year MS student here that had to take another semester in order to graduate.

Frustration is normal. Super normal. It's something I've become familiar with the last two years. The big thing, at least for me, is to push on. I also tell my students to "know when to quit." What that means is not when to give up, but when to step away, take a break, and come back with a clear head. Sometimes a solution comes after you've slept for the night, had a meal, or played a video game.

Of course, managing the frustration needs to be done healthily. Admittedly, I've wanted to throw things across the room, break cups and plates, even light things on fire (I didn't, thankfully). This behavior has also led to drinking more than I should. Find healthy ways to relieve stress - take a walk, eat a snack, talk to a friend, laugh at a comedy.

Practice makes it better. It's normal to be frustrated. You're not alone.